# Trying to make a timer which resets at the main Menu

Tags: visual-studio, timer, 2d

I have a timer for a game in Unity and I have it carrying across to each new scene and working. The issue is I also want the timer to reset when the MainMenu scene has loaded and I can not for the life of me get this to work. Help would be appreciated, code's below -

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour

{

public Text TimerText;

public float StartTime = 0f;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         string Scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
         if (Scene == "MainMenu")
         {
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
         }
         else
         {
             DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
         }
     }
     void Update()
     {
         float t = Time.time - StartTime;
         string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
         string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
         TimerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
2    public void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
3    {
4    }
```

Then check the current scene, and reset the timer if the new scene is the menu

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should mention I am new to C# Script, would I put this somewhere in my current code as above? Or would I alter what i already have to make it fit in? Just for some clarification there, and how exactly would I use this to check the scene's name?

Comment: I am an intermediate so I am not the best too but your code looks good and to check the scene just do like you did in your script (2 first lines in your Start function)

Answer (score 0):

Don't destroy the game object when main menu is loaded. Just set the time to 0 and make the game object last for all the scenes. Thus since the game object is available to all the scenes, create a bool variable called shouldCountTime. In the update function, just say if shouldCountTime == true then timer code is executed else not. When main menu is loaded, set time to zero and shouldCountTime to false. In start check if the scene loaded is not the main menu, then set shouldCountTime to true.

Code should look like:

```cs
void Start() {
    if(SceneManager.getActiveScene.name != "MainMenu") {
        shouldCountTime = true;
    } else {
        shouldCountTime = false;
        Time = 0;
    }


void Update(){

    if(shouldCountTime){

        Time += Time.deltaTime;
//All the timer code

}}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a ton for this, it's been extremly helpful. I have run into another issue however, for the timer the script I'm using is the script above as posted. I'm getting an issue on the TimerText.time line, where unity is telling me Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Have you set the timer text in the inspector. Moreover remember to convert the time float to string before assigning it to the text element. I.e. Timer.text = time.ToString();

Comment: You have used TimerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds; please correct it to     TimerText.text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + second.ToString();